# shared_from_this throws bad_weak_ptr with boost::asio

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

First, I have read all related questions listed.

They say, "you must have an existing shared_ptr to this before you can use shared_from_this." As far as I can see, there is no way I am violating that condition. I create the instance of Foo as a shared_ptr and enforced that it is always created as a shared_ptr. I then, stored the shared_ptr in a collection. Yet, I still get the bad_weak_ptr exception when shared_from_this is called.

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
class Foo : std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
public:

    typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> SharedPtr;

    // Ensure all instances are created as shared_ptr in order to fulfill requirements for shared_from_this
    static Foo::SharedPtr Create()
    {
        return Foo::SharedPtr(new Foo());
    };

    Foo(const Foo &) = delete;
    Foo(Foo &&) = delete;
    Foo & operator = (const Foo &) = delete;
    Foo & operator = (Foo &&) = delete;
    ~Foo() {};

    // We have to defer the start until we are fully constructed because we share_from_this()
    void Start()
    {
        DoStuff();
    }

private:

    Foo() {}

    void DoStuff()
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
    }
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo::SharedPtr> foos;
    Foo::SharedPtr foo = Foo::Create();
    foos.emplace_back(foo);
    foo->Start();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: I don't believe that's minimal. Are you suggesting that there is not a single expression that couldn't be removed without preventing the reproduction of the problem? While it is not necessarily mandatory to remove all such expressions, the larger the example, the more important it is to remove as much as possible. There are extremely few programming problems that cannot be reduced to a small example. I don't always ask for MCVE on long program listings, but I often do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must inherit `enable_shared_from_this` with `public` specifier according to

> Publicly inheriting from std::enable_shared_from_this provides the type T with a member function shared_from_this.

from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this.

So write

```
class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you start the threads before ever posting work, so the `io_service::run()` is prone to complete before `DoAccept` is actually done.

Next, the base class must be PUBLIC for enable_shared_from_this to work:

```
class Connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection> {
```

Working self-contained code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
namespace SomeNamespace{
struct Logger {
    enum { LOGGER_SEVERITY_INFO };
    void Log(std::string const& msg, std::string const& file, unsigned line, int level) const {
        static std::mutex mx;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mx);
        std::cout << file << ":" << line << " level:" << level << " " << msg << "\n";
    }
    template <typename... Args>
    void LogF(std::string const& msg, Args const&... args) const {
        static std::mutex mx;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mx);
        static char buf[2048];
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf)-1, msg.c_str(), args...);
        std::cout << buf << "\n";
    }
    static Logger &GetInstance() {
        static Logger This;
        return This;
    }
};
} // namespace Somenamespace

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <memory>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
class ConnectionManager;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
class Connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection> {
  public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Connection> SharedPtr;

    // Ensure all instances are created as shared_ptr in order to fulfill requirements for shared_from_this
    static Connection::SharedPtr Create(ConnectionManager *connectionManager, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket);

    Connection(const Connection &) = delete;
    Connection(Connection &&) = delete;
    Connection &operator=(const Connection &) = delete;
    Connection &operator=(Connection &&) = delete;
    ~Connection();

    // We have to defer the start until we are fully constructed because we share_from_this()
    void Start();
    void Stop();

    void Send(const std::vector<char> &data);

  private:
    ConnectionManager *m_owner;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket;
    std::atomic<bool> m_stopped;
    boost::asio::streambuf m_receiveBuffer;
    mutable std::mutex m_sendMutex;
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> > m_sendBuffers;
    bool m_sending;

    std::vector<char> m_allReadData; // for testing

    Connection(ConnectionManager *connectionManager, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket);

    void DoReceive();
    void DoSend();
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

//#include "Connection.h"
//#include "ConnectionManager.h"
//**ConnectionManager.h **

//#pragma once

//#include "Connection.h"

// Boost Includes
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

// Standard Includes
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
class ConnectionManager {
  public:
    ConnectionManager(unsigned port, size_t numThreads);
    ConnectionManager(const ConnectionManager &) = delete;
    ConnectionManager(ConnectionManager &&) = delete;
    ConnectionManager &operator=(const ConnectionManager &) = delete;
    ConnectionManager &operator=(ConnectionManager &&) = delete;
    ~ConnectionManager();

    void Start();
    void Stop();

    void OnConnectionClosed(Connection::SharedPtr connection);

  protected:
    boost::asio::io_service m_io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_listenSocket;
    std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;

    mutable std::mutex m_connectionsMutex;
    std::vector<Connection::SharedPtr> m_connections;

    void IoServiceThreadProc();

    void DoAccept();
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <algorithm>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
Connection::SharedPtr Connection::Create(ConnectionManager *connectionManager, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket) {
    return Connection::SharedPtr(new Connection(connectionManager, std::move(socket)));
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
Connection::Connection(ConnectionManager *connectionManager, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket)
        : m_owner(connectionManager), m_socket(std::move(socket)), m_stopped(false), m_receiveBuffer(), m_sendMutex(),
          m_sendBuffers(), m_sending(false), m_allReadData() {}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
Connection::~Connection() {
    // Boost uses RAII, so we don't have anything to do. Let thier destructors take care of business
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
void Connection::Start() { DoReceive(); }

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
void Connection::Stop() {
    // The entire connection class is only kept alive, because it is a shared pointer and always has a ref count
    // as a consequence of the outstanding async receive call that gets posted every time we receive.
    // Once we stop posting another receive in the receive handler and once our owner release any references to
    // us, we will get destroyed.
    m_stopped = true;
    m_owner->OnConnectionClosed(shared_from_this());
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
void Connection::Send(const std::vector<char> &data) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_sendMutex);

    // If the send buffers do not exist, then create them
    if (!m_sendBuffers) {
        m_sendBuffers = std::make_shared<std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> >();
    }

    // Copy the data to be sent to the send buffers
    m_sendBuffers->emplace_back(boost::asio::buffer(data));

    DoSend();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
void Connection::DoSend() {
    // According to the boost documentation, we cannot issue an async_write while one is already outstanding
    //
    // If that is the case, it is OK, because we've added the data to be sent to a new set of buffers back in
    // the Send method. Notice how the original buffer is moved, so therefore will be null below and how Send
    // will create new buffers and accumulate data to be sent until we complete in the lamda
    //
    // When we complete in the lamda, if we have any new data to be sent, we call DoSend once again.
    //
    // It is important though, that DoSend is only called from the lambda below and the Send method.

    if (!m_sending && m_sendBuffers) {
        m_sending = true;
        auto copy = std::move(m_sendBuffers);
        auto self(shared_from_this());

        boost::asio::async_write(m_socket, *copy,
             [self, copy](const boost::system::error_code &errorCode, size_t bytes_transferred) {
                 std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(self->m_sendMutex);
                 self->m_sending = false;

                 if (errorCode) {
                     // An error occurred
                     return;
                 }

                 self->DoSend();
             });
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
void Connection::DoReceive() {
    SomeNamespace::Logger::GetInstance().Log(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__, SomeNamespace::Logger::LOGGER_SEVERITY_INFO);
    auto self(shared_from_this()); // ***EXCEPTION HERE****

    boost::asio::async_read_until(m_socket, m_receiveBuffer, '#',
      [self](const boost::system::error_code &errorCode, size_t bytesRead) {
          if (errorCode) {
              // Notify our masters that we are ready to be destroyed
              self->m_owner->OnConnectionClosed(self);

              // An error occured
              return;
          }

          // Grab the read data
          std::istream stream(&self->m_receiveBuffer);
          std::string data;
          std::getline(stream, data, '#');

          // Issue the next receive
          if (!self->m_stopped) {
              self->DoReceive();
          }
      });
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

//**ConnectionManager.cpp **

//#include "ConnectionManager.h"

//#include "Logger.h"

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <system_error>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionManager::ConnectionManager(unsigned port, size_t numThreads)
        : m_io_service(), m_acceptor(m_io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)),
          m_listenSocket(m_io_service), m_threads(numThreads) {}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionManager::~ConnectionManager() { Stop(); }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ConnectionManager::Start() {
    if (m_io_service.stopped()) {
        m_io_service.reset();
    }

    DoAccept();

    for (auto &thread : m_threads) {
        if (!thread.joinable()) {
            thread = std::thread(&ConnectionManager::IoServiceThreadProc, this);
        }
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ConnectionManager::Stop() {
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_connectionsMutex);
        m_connections.clear();
    }

    // TODO - Will the stopping of the io_service be enough to kill all the connections and ultimately have them get
    // destroyed?
    //        Because remember they have outstanding ref count to thier shared_ptr in the async handlers
    m_io_service.stop();

    for (auto &thread : m_threads) {
        if (thread.joinable()) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ConnectionManager::IoServiceThreadProc() {
    try {
        // Log that we are starting the io_service thread
        {
            const std::string msg("io_service socket thread starting.");
            SomeNamespace::Logger::GetInstance().Log(msg, __FILE__, __LINE__,
                                                      SomeNamespace::Logger::LOGGER_SEVERITY_INFO);
        }

        // Run the asynchronous callbacks from the socket on this thread
        // Until the io_service is stopped from another thread
        m_io_service.run();
    } catch (std::system_error &e) {
        SomeNamespace::Logger::GetInstance().LogF("System error caught in io_service socket thread. Error Code: %d", e.code().value());
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        SomeNamespace::Logger::GetInstance().LogF("Standard exception caught in io_service socket thread. Exception: %s", e.what());
    } catch (...) {
        SomeNamespace::Logger::GetInstance().LogF("Unhandled exception caught in io_service socket thread.");
    }

    SomeNamespace::Logger::GetInstance().LogF("io_service socket thread exiting."); 
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ConnectionManager::DoAccept() {
    SomeNamespace::Logger::GetInstance().Log(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__, SomeNamespace::Logger::LOGGER_SEVERITY_INFO);

    m_acceptor.async_accept(m_listenSocket, [this](const boost::system::error_code errorCode) {
        if (errorCode) {
            return;
        }

        {
            // Create the connection from the connected socket
            Connection::SharedPtr connection = Connection::Create(this, m_listenSocket);
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_connectionsMutex);
                m_connections.push_back(connection);
                connection->Start();
            }
        }

        DoAccept();
    });
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ConnectionManager::OnConnectionClosed(Connection::SharedPtr connection) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_connectionsMutex);

    auto itConnection = std::find(m_connections.begin(), m_connections.end(), connection);
    if (itConnection != m_connections.end()) {
        m_connections.erase(itConnection);
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//**main.cpp**
//#include "ConnectionManager.h"

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    ConnectionManager connectionManager(4000, 2);
    connectionManager.Start();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(1));

    connectionManager.Stop();
}
```