# shared_from_this() causes std::bad_weak_ptr even when correctly using make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I am creating a C++ server application using standalone Asio and C++11 and am getting an error, which is why I am asking for help.

### The error

In the class `worker_thread`, during the call to `shared_from_this()`, a `bad_weak_ptr` exception is raised, which causes the program to crash.

### The layout

1. The class `connection_manager` creates and stores objects of type `std::shared_ptr<worker_thread>` inside a `std::vector` container
2. The class `worker_thread` inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this<worker_thread>`.
3. The class `worker_thread` creates objects of type `std::shared_ptr<connection>`.
4. The class `connection` requires a pointer (which is a shared pointer) to the class `worker_thread`, so that in can call the `void handle_finish(std::shared_ptr<connection>)`

### Program flow

1. The class `worker_thread` is created via its constructor, from the class `connection_manager` using `std::make_shared<worker_thread>` with two shared pointers as parameters.
2. `void init()` is called from `worker_thread` by `connection_manager`
3. Later in the program, `connection_manager` calls `std::shared_ptr<connection> get_available_connection()` from `worker_thread`
4. During this method's execution, a new `connection` is created via `std::make_shared<connection>`, and one of the arguments is the shared pointer to the **current** `worker_thread` obtained via `shared_from_this()`
5. During the `shared_from_this()` call, the program crashes with a `bad_weak_ptr` exception.

### Research

From my research, the most common causes of this error are:

1. When `shared_from_this()` is called within a constructor (or a function which is called by the constructor)
2. When there is no existing `std::shared_ptr` pointing to the object.

In my program:

1. The call to the constructor and the `get_available_connection()` are separate, and through outputing lines in the terminal, it seems that the `worker_thread` is constructed and initialised by the time the call to `get_available_connection()` occurs
2. The `connection_manager` class holds a shared pointer to every `worker_thread` object.

### Code

**All `something_ptr` are `std::shared_ptr<something>`**

#### Header files

**`connection_manager.hpp`**

```
typedef asio::executor_work_guard<asio::io_context::executor_type>
    io_context_work;
std::vector<worker_thread_ptr> workers;
std::vector<io_context_ptr> io_contexts;
std::vector<io_context_work> work;
```

**`worker_thread.hpp`**

```
class worker_thread : std::enable_shared_from_this<worker_thread> {
public:

/// Create a worker thread.
explicit worker_thread(io_context_ptr io, config_ptr vars_global);

void init();
void join();

connection_ptr get_available_connection();
//...
```

**`connection.hpp`**

```
explicit connection(std::shared_ptr<worker_thread> worker,
            std::shared_ptr<asio::io_context> io, 
            config_ptr vars_parent);
```

#### Source files

**`connection_manager.cpp`**

```
connection_manager::connection_manager(config_ptr vars) {
    std::size_t number_of_threads = vars->worker_threads;
    while(number_of_threads > 0) {
        io_context_ptr io_context(new asio::io_context);
        io_contexts.push_back(io_context);
        work.push_back(asio::make_work_guard(*io_context));

        worker_thread_ptr worker =
            std::make_shared<worker_thread>(io_context, vars);
        workers.push_back(worker);

        worker->init();

        --number_of_threads;
    }   
} 

connection_ptr connection_manager::get_available_connection() {
    std::size_t index_of_min_thread = 0;
    std::size_t worker_count = workers.size();
    for(std::size_t i = 1; i < worker_count; ++i) {
        if(workers[i]->active_connection_count() <
                workers[index_of_min_thread]->active_connection_count())
            index_of_min_thread = i;
    }
    return workers[index_of_min_thread]->get_available_connection();
}
```

**`worker_thread.cpp`**

```
worker_thread::worker_thread(io_context_ptr io, 
        config_ptr vars_global)
    :io_context(io), active_conn_count(0), vars(vars_global),
    worker(
        [this]() {
            if(io_context)
                io_context->run();
        }   
    ) {}

void worker_thread::init() {
    //Additional initialisation, this is called by connection_manager
    //after this thread's construction
}   

connection_ptr worker_thread::get_available_connection() {
    connection_ptr conn;
    if(!available_connections.empty()) {
        conn = available_connections.front();
        available_connections.pop();
        active_connections.insert(conn);
        return conn;
    } else {
        conn = std::make_shared<connection>(shared_from_this(), io_context, vars);
        active_connections.insert(conn);
        return conn;
    }
}
```

I am sorry if this question has been answered before, but I tried to resolve this, and after trying for some time, I decided it would be better to ask for help.

**EDIT**
Here is a minimum test, which fails. It requires CMake, and **you might have to change the minimum required version**.

[Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MqWhwFXppSHWNRCETKP19WmE507iHiAx)

Comment: Please take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i do not see any of the commen mistakes.
did you check that you do not break anything because of multi-threaded access? (use locks where necessary), sometimes this errors have their cause in some memory corruption or are follow-up of some "undefined behaviour" operation

Comment: While the program is multithreaded, the threads which are created are doing nothing until the `get_available_connection()` call arrives from the main thread, which is why I believe that this is not the problem. Nevertheless, I will check.

Comment: What's the stacktrace? Better yet, try using the debugger!

Comment: #9  0x000055555557b8e7 in std::shared_ptr<musync::server::worker_thread>::shared_ptr<musync::server::worker_thread, void> (this=0x7fffffffe560, 
    __r=std::weak_ptr<musync::server::worker_thread> (empty) = {...})#10 0x000055555557b535 in std::enable_shared_from_this<musync::server::worker_thread>::shared_from_this (this=0x5555557ad790)
    #11 in musync::server::worker_thread::get_available_connection (this=0x5555557ad790)
    #12 in musync::server::connection_manager::get_available_connection
    #13 in musync::server::server::do_accept
    #14 in musync::server::server::init

Comment: You need to *publicly* inherit from [`enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) otherwise the `weak_ptr<T>` that `enable_shared_from_this<T>` holds is never initialized.

Comment: @SeanCline isn't that what this line does `class worker_thread : std::enable_shared_from_this<worker_thread>`

Comment: @PetarNikić `class`es inherit *privately* by default. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4797014/1020072).

Comment: @SeanCline can you please write it a little bit more formally as an answer so that I can mark it as the answer? You've helped me! Thank you!

Comment: Glad that was it. Looks like I've been beaten to the punch on the answer. @NinaKaprez's answer covers it.

Comment: Reworded the title to make this an excellent search hit for this recurring pitfall. (I saw it before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916281/shared-from-this-throws-bad-weak-ptr-with-boostasio/47929479#47929479 but it took too long for me to realize it here, again). This stuff is what [SO] is made for

Comment: Have you considered using a plain `weak_ptr` member that you initialize yourself instead of that automagic `enable_shared_from_this`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think your problem might be that you use default **`private`** inheritance.

here is a simple example of a program that crashes:

```
class GoodUsage : public std::enable_shared_from_this<GoodUsage>
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        auto good = shared_from_this();
    }
};

class BadUsage : std::enable_shared_from_this<BadUsage> // private inheritance
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        auto bad = shared_from_this();
    }
};


int main()
{
    auto good = std::make_shared<GoodUsage>();
    auto bad = std::make_shared<BadUsage>();
    good->DoSomething(); // ok
    bad->DoSomething(); // throws std::bad_weak_ptr    
}
```